# How to check mac address of the cable?

Tags: internet, mac-address

For example I have a cable with an Internet connection, but I don't know the mac address of this connection. When I plug it to my laptop, it doesn't work. How could I get it from a command-line?

`UPD`: Ok. Some network administrator that supplies me with internet needs to know mac-address of my machine for my normal using. So when I plug the cable to right laptop - internet works, when I plug it to wrong - doesn't. I can manually replace mac-address of "wrong" machine to right one in `ip link` or `ifconfig`, but when I only know mac-address. How can I do it, when I don't know this mac-address, "right" laptop and administrator are missing?

Comment: Sounds like it might be easier to tell the network administrator the other mac address?

Comment: That's right, but I can't believe that there is no way to find this right mac with  a bash...

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm trying to figure out what you mean here. A cable by itself does not have a MAC address. A networked piece of hardware like a NIC (Network Interface Card) or a ROKU, PlayStation, etc. will have a MAC address aka: Hardware/physical address. So, if you are on the same network (Same LAN) as the hardware you are attempting to retrieve the MAC address of you can use

```
arp -a
```

or you can map your network. This is assuming you have a 192.168.0.x scheme, if not change it to your IP scheme. Common LAN IP Schemes are 10.0.0.1, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1

```
sudo nmap -sP -n 192.168.0.0/24
```

Comment: Check the UPD, please.